# change onclick in html to addevent listener

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Here I want to change the *onclick="currentSlide(1)* in my html to a ADDEVENTLISTENER in my javascript. It's an image gallery, all works fine but I want to change the way this action is triggered,

```
        <div class="product__slide-row">
        
              <div class="product__row-images">
                <img class="demo cursor product__row-img" src="../imgs/productos/licuadora/1.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="The Woods">
              </div>
        
              <div class="product__row-images">
                <img class="demo cursor product__row-img" src="../imgs/productos/licuadora/2.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Cinque Terre">
              </div>
        
              <div class="product__row-images">
                <img class="demo cursor product__row-img" src="../imgs/productos/licuadora/3.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="Mountains and fjords">
              </div>
        
              <div class="product__row-images">
                <img class="demo cursor product__row-img" src="../imgs/productos/licuadora/4.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="Northern Lights">
              </div>
        
              <div class="product__row-images">
                <img class="demo cursor product__row-img" src="../imgs/productos/licuadora/5.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(5)" alt="Nature and sunrise">
              </div>    
        
              <div class="product__row-images">
                <img class="demo cursor product__row-img" src="../imgs/productos/licuadora/6.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(6)" alt="Snowy Mountains">
              </div>
        </div>
```

```
    var slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);
    
    
    function currentSlide(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }
    
    function showSlides(n) {
      var i;
      var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("product__slide-images");
    
    
      if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
      if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
      for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
          slides[i].style.display = "none";
      }
     
    
      slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    }
```

Comment: Hey man, it would work in you favor if you'd put in some effort into making your question easy to read and uncluttered. Remove the plead for help and try to be way more specific about what you're trying to make, what isn't working and what it *should* do. Also those dots, really?

Comment: The doc is quite full of examples : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener ! Good luck